# Trying to understand how to call a future forecast with Dark Sky API

Tags: php, laravel, darksky

Trying to understand how to write this function to get a 6-day forecast for 2 days from now. Right now it returns an 8 day forecast including today. If I give it the atTime it gives me one forecast during that day. I'm using php (laravel)

```
        $two_days_forcast = Carbon::now()->addDay(2)->timestamp;

    if ($users->latitude) {
        $weather = DarkSky::location($users->latitude, $users->longitude)
        ->atTime($two_days_forcast)
        ->daily();
        return $weather;
```

Any help would be appreciated. If I don't add the ->atTime it gives me the 8 day forecast.

Comment: Why don't just slice the original array? BTW, if you put an array of all the days in th atTime function what happens??

Comment: if you mean something like this    

        $two_days_forcast = Carbon::now()->addDay(2)->timestamp;
        $three_days_forcast = Carbon::now()->addDay(3)->timestamp;
    
        if ($users->latitude) {
            $weather = DarkSky::location($users->latitude, $users->longitude)
            ->atTime([$two_days_forcast,$three_days_forcast])
            ->daily();
            return $weather;
          
        } else {

then it throws a Notice: Array to string conversion